# getting an error with detectAndCompute with AKAZE_create

Tags: python, opencv

Here's my code:

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('a.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
feat = cv2.AKAZE_create(500)
keypoints, descriptors = feat.detectAndCompute(imGray, None)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "akaze.py", line 6, in <module>
    keypoints, descriptors = feat.detectAndCompute(imGray, None)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/features2d/src/kaze/AKAZEFeatures.cpp:1294: error: (-215:Assertion failed) x0 - 6 * scale >= 0 && x0 + 6 * scale < Lx.cols in function 'Sample_Derivative_Response_Radius6'
```

It works fine if I replace `AKAZE_create` with a different feature descriptor extractor, e.g. `ORB_create`.

Am I doing something wrong or does `detectAndCompute` just not work with `AKAZE_create`?

I'm running Python 3.8.10 and OpenCV 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to limit the number of keypoints but for `AKAZE_create` there is no option to limit that number as `Rotem` pointed out in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616696/opencv4-1-0-error-215assertion-failed-y0-6-scale-0-y0-6-sca)

You can replace `feat = cv2.AKAZE_create(500)` with `feat = cv2.AKAZE_create()`

For documentation of AKAZE constructor [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d8/d30/classcv_1_1AKAZE.html#aee9025aea852275a424e1b5934c79103)